# Using qualified name in the global scope

Tags: c++

I've written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    int z=::b;
}

int b=5;

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::z;
}
```

and I expected that it was worked correctly. It is because:

> A name prefixed by the unary scope operator :: (5.1) is looked up in
>   global scope, in the translation unit where it is used. The name shall
>   be declared in global namespace scope or shall be a name whose
>   declaration is visible in global scope because of a using-directive
>   (3.4.3.2). The use of :: allows a global name to be referred to even
>   if its identifier has been hidden (3.3.10).

This quote is said nothing about that the variable must be declare lexically before using of qualified id.

Answer (score 0):

> The name shall be declared in global namespace scope

You have to write:

```
int b=5;

namespace A
{
    int z=::b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why does declaration must be lexically before the it is using as qualified-id. I cant find anything about it in the standard.

Comment: The question is *why* does it have to be declared before (I guess it means find the relevant quote from the standard...)

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I'm looking for a quote from the standard.

Comment: In C++ in almost all cases variables have to be declared before usage. You can't write `a = 3; int a;`. Why should it be different here?

Answer (score 0):

From **3.3.2 Point of declaration:**

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its
>   initializer (if any), except as noted below. [ Example:
>
> ```
>  int x = 12;
>  { int x = x; }
>    Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. — end example ]
> ```

This effectively enforces the *declare-before-use* in C++ aside from exceptions such as functions in a class scope, etc.

Comment: I know what does point of declaration mean. I want to find a corresponding lookup rule.